# Dreamweaver replace with regular expression

Tags: regex, adobe, dreamweaver, replace

I'm having a problem with a simple Find and Replace in Dreamweaver using a regex.

This is what's in my find box:

```
<div id="title">([^ö]*)</div>
```

This is what's in my replace box

```
<div id="title">
    <div class="center">
       $1
       <span>hello there</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I run the find and replace above on this:

```
<div id="title"><h1>Page title</h1></div>
<div class="content">
   more content
</div>
```

I can't get to this result:

```
<div id="title">
    <div class="center">
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        <span>hello there</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
   more content
</div>
```

Because the content of de find box does not define that I only want the content between < div id="title" > and the first < /div >...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching markup languages with regexes is tricky to say the least.

In your case (assuming that the `<div>` tags you're searching and replacing won't contain any nested `<div>` tags), you could get by with using

```
<div id="title">([\s\S]*?)</div>
```

as your search regex.

- `[\s\S]` matches any character,
  including linebreaks (that's more
  explicit than `[^ö]`, I'd say).
- `*`
  matches zero or more of those
- `?`
  makes the star "lazy", meaning that
  it will match as few characters as
  possible - thereby ensuring that the
  match will stop at the next `</div>`.